# getting issue while Re Running the request - JMeter

Tags: database, loops, jmeter

Scenario:
After login into the application, system check number of pending files and if any pending file present then get assign to the user. The maximum files that can be assigned to user is two.

Once user process the first files, again system check for the pending files and if any pending file present then get assign to the user.

For this I used Loop Controller, but it not working.

```
Thread Group
    HTTP Request - Login
    JDBC Connection Configuration
    JDBC Request
        JSR223 PostProcessor
            List<String> fileIDListresultSet = vars.getObject("File_ID")
            vars.put("fileIDListSize", String.valueOf(fileIDListresultSet.size()))
    Loop Controller
        ${fileIDListSize}
            HTTP Request - 1 Lock File
                JSR223 PreProcessor
                    def counterVal = vars.get("fileIDCounter") as int
                    def fileIDListresultSet = vars.getObject("File_ID").get(counterVal).get("FileId")
                    vars.put("fileId",fileIDListresultSet.toString())
            HTTP Request - 2 Process File
            JDBC Request
                JSR223 PostProcessor
                List<String> fileIDListresultSet = vars.getObject("File_ID")
                vars.put("fileIDListSize", String.valueOf(fileIDListresultSet.size()))
    Counter
```

Comment: any help on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. From the first glance your [Counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) placement is incorrect, it needs to be a child of the Loop Controller, see [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) article for more details
2. You don't even need the counter as the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) exposes a special variable holding current iteration number - `${__jm__Loop Controller__idx}`
3. In any case we don't have any possibility to help you unless you show the values of these `File_ID`, `fileIDListSize`, `fileIDCounter`, `FileId` and `fileId` for each iteration (can be obtained using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)) along with [jmeter.log file contents](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)